# How to unzip file in C# using Ioniczip

Tags: c#, unzip

How do I extract files from previously IonicZipped??
Basically my project involves encoding and decoding(steganography) by executing the following commands

```
; Source2.jpg contains n number of files
copy /b Source1.jpg + Source2.jpg destination.jpg
copy /d destination.jpg decode.zip
```

the first command prompt statement worked perfectly, so did the second but im not able to extract "decode.zip"

```
ZipFile zip = new ZipFile();
zip.ExtractAll(p2 + "\\decode.zip"); //p2 contains Directory
```

Comment: So what happens when you call `ExtractAll`? An exception? An error? Not the files you wanted?

Comment: Note that the shell `copy /d` command does not have anything to do with zip files.

Comment: Is it similar to this? You added 18 and 6 and got 24. Now you ask, "which numbers I used to get 24".

Comment: 1)"An unhandled exception of type'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occured in mdcorlib.dll
Additional information: Could not find 'C:\Users\Sugosh\Desktop\New folder\decode.zip'" its saying its unable to find the file but decode.zip exists in New folder
2)"copy /b a.jpg + b.zip c.jpg" hides a.jpg and b.zip in c.jpg with a.jpg's image in c.jpg. /b means binay
"copy /d c.jpg d.zip" gives the content present in c.jpg with extension .zip and store it as d.zip /d means Decode

Comment: @L.B
Kinda similar but consider different data types.. not just integers. a.jpg+b.zip=c.jpg, "we need which .zip is used in c.jpg" It means you are masking b.zip with a.jpg image.
I got the b.zip file but unable to extract it. As stated in the above comment got an exception.

Comment: I'm able to extract normal zip files but unable to open zip files created by command prompt. It also said "An unhandled exception of type 'Ionic.Zip.ZipException' occurred in Ionic.Zip.dll

Additional information: Cannot read that as a ZipFile"
This is the crucial part of the project and i cant ignore it. How do i Open such zip files. Thanks for help :)

Comment: If I cant unzip it using C# commands, is there any command for CommandPrompt to unzip a zip file? Either one would be helpful.